# How to control when a component renders? React js for adding a comment to a post

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-paper-w39kvw?file=/src/components/Comments.js:141-200

```
const initialState = {
    comments: [
        {
            id: 1,
            username: "Kevin",
            date: "3 hours ago",
            text: "Hello",
            votes: 12,
            upvoted: false,
            downvoted: false,
            comments: []
        }

    ]
}
```

In my comments code I have a useSelector

```
const { comments } = useSelector(state => state.comments)
```

this renders all the comments everytime a new comment is added

as shown here using react dev tools add on to highlight when a component renders: https://i.gyazo.com/43a93b6d07a5802d91d9f68684e5ded5.mp4

I tried to use `React.memo` to memoize the comment but im not sure why that didn't work. Is there anyway to stop rendering all the comments when a comment gets added?

Comment: You're mapping through an array of ``comments`` which you then updates, so it has to render the whole array when it changes.

Comment: What would be the ideal way to do it then?

Comment: You would usually put the memo/useCallback on the individual component (i.e. each object in comments).

Comment: I did that. I used React.memo on the entire comment component. Still, it would render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a component is wrapped in React.memo(), React renders the component and memoizes the result. Before the next render, if the new props are the same, React reuses the memoized result skipping the next rendering.

In your code below, you are passing the `allComments` function to the comment component.

```
  const allComments = (comments, bg) => {
    const output = comments.map((comment) => {
      return (
        <Comment
          key={comment.id}
          comment={comment}
          allComments={allComments} // the function get's passed as new function object on each rerender
          bg={bg}
        />
      );
    });

    return output;
  };
```

> what is the problem then and why this behavior?

because of the function equality check, functions in javascript are treated as firstclass citizens, in other word, functions are objects.

```
function factory() {
  return (a, b) => a + b;
}
const sum1 = factory();
const sum2 = factory();
sum1(1, 2); // => 3
sum2(1, 2); // => 3
sum1 === sum2; // => false
sum1 === sum1; // => true
```

The functions **sum1** and **sum2** share the same code source but they are different function objects. Comparing them sum1 === sum2 evaluates to false. this is how Javascript works.

In your code, a new function object `allComments` gets created in each render by react, which is eventually gets passed as a new prop to the `React.memo()`. By default `React.memo()` does a shallow comparison of props and objects of props. which is why it triggers the a new rerender.

Now we understand deeply what was the problem and what causes this behavior.

The solution is to wrap your `allComments` with `useCallback`

What is the purpose of **useCallback**? it maintain a single function instance between renderings. and thus `React.memo()` will work.

```
 const allComments = useCallback((comments, bg) => {
    const output = comments.map((comment) => {
      return (
        <Comment
          key={comment.id}
          comment={comment}
          allComments={allComments}
          bg={bg}
        />
      );
    });

    return output;
  },[]);
```